# Change Andoid screen timeout using Android Management API

Tags: android-management-api

We have a tablet provisioned using the Android Management API running a web-app (in Google Chrome) in kiosk mode. Per default the tablet will automatically turn off the screen after a moment.

Would it be possible to configure a parameter in the policy that prevents the screen from turning off?

Answer (score 0):

**Android Management API** does not offer a prevent screen-off option. There are options within app development such as `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` and OEM’s of devices sometimes offer screen off options as well in OEM Managed Configs.

You can consider using the [**stayOnPluggedModes**](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#BatteryPluggedMode) to [“AC”, “USB”]. It is used to select which battery modes the device is plugged in for which the device stays on. When using this setting, it is recommended to clear the `maximumTimeToLock` so that the device doesn’t lock itself while it stays on.

If you want to stay up to date with the latest updates for Android enterprise, we suggest that you [join the Android Management API mailing list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes) to receive monthly updates and service advisories directly to your inbox.